# Are there better way to do this with nuget or more establish code?

Tags: vb.net, hex, byte

I make this code/function

```
Protected Overridable Function computeSig(content As String, secret As String) As String
    Dim secretinBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secret1) 'Turn secret hex into bytes (0-9a-f)
    Dim hasher2 = New System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(secretinBytes) 'create hashers based on those bytes
    Dim hashbytes = hasher2.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)) 'compute the hash and get bytes
    Dim sighash2 = BitConverter.ToString(hashbytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower() 'turn bytes into hex string (0-9a-f)

    Return sighash2
End Function
```

I wonder if there is a nuget or more standard way that can replace that function with one line of code.

I am doing fine with those code however, it's easier to ask for help and explain what I am doing if I use a moire famous code.

Basically, what it does is compute has of certain content, usually function body and stuff, and hash it with certain secret.

Comment: It's just `Return String.Concat(Array.ConvertAll(sigs, Function(b) b.ToString("x2")))` or `Return String.Concat(sigs.Select(Function(b) b.ToString("x2")))`

Comment: Still too complicated. I wonder if cryptoexchange.net nugget have a way for this?

Comment: Too complicated? It's a line of code. If you want to generate less garbage, then aggregate to a StringBuilder, e.g., `Return sigs.Aggregate(New StringBuilder(sigs.Length * 2), Function(s, b) s.Append(b.ToString("X2"))).ToString()` -- The whole method is this line of code.

Comment: I modified the question a bit. It's now the whole thing. I turned it into a function but I wonder if there is a more standard function